# Object identification issues in UFT 12.5

Tags: angularjs, hp-uft

I have an AUT (angular JS developed). I would like to know does uft have object recognition issues with objects in the development platform?

I have tried using DP approach, .set, fire event, replay time method and still it's not setting a value in my WebEdit field, by throwing the error message "object not identified/ one or more objects with same property"

My requirement is to enter a value in the WebEdit, then based on the value entered, corresponding options are displayed(not drop-down) and I need to select a value from the options.

This is my current code:

```vbs
Dim current_Page 
Set current_Page = Browser("Start").Page("Start") 
current_Page.Sync 
Dim oDesc 
Set oDesc = Description.Create 'Create an empty description 
oDesc("micClass").value = "WebEdit" 
oDesc("type").value= "text" 
oDesc("name").value= "locationSearch" 
oDesc("html tag").value= "INPUT" 
Wait 2 
If current_Page.WebEdit(oDesc).Exist(1) Then 
    current_Page.WebEdit(oDesc).Highlight 
    current_Page.WebEdit(oDesc).Click 
End if 
current_Page.WebEdit(oDesc).set "06116"
```

Comment: You are receiving the "object not identified/ one or more objects with same property" simply because your AUT has other winedit objects with the same properties you are using to identify your object. Check the properties being used and refine them in orther to have a proper object identification

Comment: If you have the desired object mapped in your object repositories, open the *Object Repository Manager*, select your mapped object and click in **[None. Click to Add]** next to the *Visual relation identifier settings* on the right pane. After that, click on **Preview** button on the window that will open. It will highlight on screen and show to you how many objects you have in your AUT that share the same properties. After that you can refine your object identification until you have only one object identified. For further assistance, please provide your code

Comment: Hii Victor thanks for the comment.

Comment: please find the below code it works till click but after hat it skipps the script Dim oDesc
 Set oDesc = Description.Create 
 oDesc("micClass").value = "WebEdit"
 oDesc("type").value= "text"
 oDesc("name").value= "locationSearch"
 oDesc("html tag").value= "INPUT"
wait 2

 if current_Page.WebEdit(oDesc).Exist(1) then
 current_Page.WebEdit(oDesc).highlight
 current_Page.WebEdit(oDesc).Click
 End if 
 
 Setting.WebPackage("ReplayType") = 2 
 current_Page.WebEdit(oDesc).set "06116"
 Setting.WebPackage("ReplayType") = 1

Comment: Also I want click ona button  drop down and select second option from it using HP UFT. how can i do that.

Comment: Please edit your question and post the code in there. It's too hard to read it as a comment

Comment: Dim Current_Page    
Set current_Page = Browser("Start").Page("Start")
current_Page.Sync
Dim oDesc
Set oDesc = Description.Create 'Create an empty description
oDesc("micClass").value = "WebEdit"
oDesc("type").value= "text"
oDesc("name").value= "locationSearch"
oDesc("html tag").value= "INPUT"
wait 2  if current_Page.WebEdit(oDesc).Exist(1) then
current_Page.WebEdit(oDesc).highlight
current_Page.WebEdit(oDesc).Click
End if                                                             
current_Page.WebEdit(oDesc).set "06116"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are facing issues with object identification because the properties you are using to identify your desired object matches more than one object on screen.

There is no right answer on which property you should use in order to properly identify your object, although there are some properties that have higher chance of being unique and therefore will help you.
The properties I usually take into consideration when mapping and identifying my objects are:

- `micClass` - UFT recognizable class, such as WebEdit, WebElement, Link and so forth;
- `class` - the html class, very helpful, depending on the case;
- `html id` - that is a very good one, if your developer is a good guy and follows good coding practices; and
- `html tag`- also very good to use.

But this is pretty much a question of Spying the properties of your objects and analyzing your Application to make sure you will face no duplicates.

One way of spying your object properties is to hit `F12` in your browser and use the Developer toolkit from the browser.

Another way is to use the Object Spy from UFT.

In either way you should be able to identify which properties from your objects are unique. 
If you are mapping your object in Object Repository, you can also take advantage of the Visual reference identification settings to make sure you have the unique object identified, as I mentioned in my comments.
To do so, follow this steps:

1. Open the Object Repository Manager;
2. Select your mapped object;
3. Click in **[None. Click to Add]** next to the *Visual relation identifier settings* on the right pane;
4. Click on **Preview** button on the window that will open

This will highlight all objects on screen that match the properties you used to map your object and also will show to you how many objects you have in your AUT that share the same properties.
After that you can refine your object identification until you have only one object identified.

Another good way to use this resource (actually the main reason to use it) is when you simply cannot find the right properties to make your object unique to identify, because in here you can actually map another object that will always be displayed next to the object you want. In here you create a visual reference and UFT will be able to recognize your object.
You can find a very good tutorial on how to use such resource in this link:
https://www.joecolantonio.com/2012/02/03/qtp-visual-relation-identifier/

And last, but not least, if you are in object repository manager, remember to Set the `Smart Identification` property as `False`, to make sure UFT is not identifying a different object than the one you are expecting.

I believe with this tips you have more chance on properly identifying your object.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. Thanks a lot

Comment: I want to automate an e commerce website where i can choose 1 or 2 options , as per the options choosed it will show up the products/ the price. could you tell what will be the script used for the same I found                                                                           "objectSelectBox.Select "value from list". but it is not worked in Uft also with inner text method also not working. Would you be able to trouble shoot the same?

Comment: `objectSelectBox.Select "value from list"` will only work if you are capable of identifying your drop-down object as `WebList`. If your object is being identified as `WebElement` you have a harder work to do but unfortunately this would be off-topic for the current question. Please create a separate topic for that, providing the code with what you have already tried on the matter, so the community can assist you. Thank you very much :)